# dompdf word-break on chars with different style

Tags: css, dompdf, word-break

I'm trying to render text with dompdf. It should look exactly like in the browser. That works, as long as the characters of the words are not formatted:

With HTML like:

```
<span style="color: #000000; font-family:'opensans'">
    <p style="font-size: 30.57465524239px;">
        This Text is a test to show the different behaviour!
    </p>
</span>
```

**Browser text without formats**

[image]

**dompdf text without formats**

[image]

But if I want to give the characters different styles, with HTML like:

```
<span style="color: #000000; font-family:'opensans'">
    <p style="font-size: 30px;">
        This Text is a test to 
        <span style="color: #800080;">s</span>
        <span style="color: #ff0000;">h</span>
        <span style="color: #000080;">o</span>
        <span style="color: #003300;">w</span>  
        <span style="color: #000080;">t</span>
        <span style="color: #ff00ff;">h</span>
        <span style="color: #ff0000;">e
            <span style="color: #000000;">different behaviour!</span>
        </span>
    </p>
</span>
```

The browser still displays it like intended:

[image]

But dompdf displays it like `word-break: break-all;` would be active.

[image]

I have already tried to add `word-break: keep-all;` to the surrounding `<span>` or `<p>`. I have also tried to surround the words with another `<span>` or `<nobr>` element, but that didn't change anything.

So, my question is, how can I get dompdf to keep the normal `word-break` rules on words with formatted characters?

Comment: This is an issue with how dompdf determines where words break occur. Right now the library does not have any mechanism to determine how a sequence of characters related when interrupted by inline elements. Your solution probably works best for now.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have settled with a PHP function, which uses dompdf to measure the formatted textwidth and adds the necessary `<br>` where I need them.

It's not the best solution and I hope that someone will find a better one.
But for now it works for me and I'll post it here, maybe it will help someone.

[PHP dompdf wrapText](http://pastebin.com/qyNaju5j)

It takes HTML code in the form:

```
<span style="color: #000000; font-family:'opensans'">
    <p style="font-size: 30.57465524239px;">
        This Text is a test to show the different behaviour!
    </p>
</span>
```

and returns HTML code in the form:

```
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: opensans; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30.57px;">T</span>
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: opensans; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30.57px;">h</span>
...
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: opensans; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30.57px;">t</span>
<br>
<span style="color: #000000; font-family: opensans; font-weight: normal; font-size: 30.57px;">t</span>
...
```

It works quite reliable for me, because my input text is always formed exactly the same.

It takes the most style information from the inline style tags and the bold information from surrounding `<strong>`